# Openstreetmap and Overpass API, How to get metadata of all children objects

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

is it possible to return the metadata of members (or children)? Or return structured data for parent and child objects from OSM?

I have the following query which returns all wind farms in Australia, and lists the lat lon for the members (or children objects). However after numerous attempts I haven't worked out how to include the metadata (or tags) for the children, which in this case are "generator:method"="wind_turbine".

```
// @name AU wind farms

[out:json][timeout:25];
// fetch area “Australia” to search in
{{geocodeArea:Australia}}->.searchArea;
// gather results
(nwr(area.searchArea)["site"="wind_farm"];
nwr(area.searchArea)["plant:source"="wind"];);
// print results
out body geom;
```

So far I can only get the wind turbine data in a flat json format:

```
// @name AU wind turbines

[out:json][timeout:25];
// fetch area “Australia” to search in
{{geocodeArea:Australia}}->.searchArea;
// gather results
(nwr(area.searchArea)["generator:method"="wind_turbine"];);
// print results
out body geom;
```

Example wind farm: [OSM Ararat Wind Farm](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/8144683#map=12/-37.2229/143.0835)

Example wind farm member / wind turbine: [OSM Ararat Farm, Wind Turbine](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/7024788820)